# C++11: binding and storing handler functors with varying signatures

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functor

I have a `worker` class which accepts jobs from the outside via a queue.
The jobs are processed asynchronously, when they are finished, a handler function shall be called.
This handler function's signature depends on the job type. The problem is that I do not know the result value at the moment I need to store the handler in the queue so I cannot bind handler function and result value right there.

So I used a boost::variant which enumerates all possible result types so I can store all functors in the same queue.
I do not like that I have to manually enumerate the result types and I feel like my code can be simplified.

Is there any way to avoid the "boost::variant -> static_visitor" method?

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// jobs

struct DoSomeWork {};
struct AnotherJob {};

// job results

struct SomeResult { int value; };
struct AnotherResult { float fValue; };

struct worker
{
    typedef boost::variant<SomeResult, AnotherResult> JobResultVariant;    

    struct NoOp
    {
    template <typename... Ts>
    void operator()(Ts&&...) const{}
    };
    template <typename JobType, typename JobFinishedHandler = NoOp>
    void enqueue_job(const JobType& job, const JobFinishedHandler& handler = NoOp())
    {

    // enqueue job
    // ...

    // store handler
    jobFinishedHandlerQueue.push(
            std::bind(&worker::call_finished_handler<JobFinishedHandler>, this, handler, std::placeholders::_1)
            );
    }

    template <typename JobFinishedHandler>
    void call_finished_handler(const JobFinishedHandler& handler, const JobResultVariant& result)
    {
    boost::apply_visitor(dispatch_job_result<JobFinishedHandler>(handler), result);
    }

    template <typename JobFinishedHandler>
    struct dispatch_job_result : public boost::static_visitor<>
    {
    dispatch_job_result(const JobFinishedHandler& handler) : handler(handler) {}


    // check if the event handler accepts this argument
    template <typename EventType,
          class = decltype(std::declval<JobFinishedHandler>()(std::declval<EventType>()))>

    void operator()(const EventType& event) const
    {
        handler(event);
    }

    // fallback if the above check fails
    template <typename... Ts>
    void operator()(Ts&&...) const
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    const JobFinishedHandler& handler;
    };

    void run()
    {
    // do the work
    // ...
    // the actual work is omitted here
    // fake the generation of a result to be able to compile this example

    SomeResult result;
    result.value = 100;

    // result is available, now call result handler

    auto finishedHandlerWrapper = jobFinishedHandlerQueue.front();
    jobFinishedHandlerQueue.pop();
    finishedHandlerWrapper(result);
    }

    typedef std::function<void(const JobResultVariant&)> JobFinishedHandlerWrapper;
    typedef std::queue<JobFinishedHandlerWrapper> JobFinishedHandlerQueue;
    JobFinishedHandlerQueue jobFinishedHandlerQueue;
};

int main()
{
    worker w;

    auto handler = [](const SomeResult& result){ std::cout << result.value << std::endl; };
    w.enqueue_job(DoSomeWork(), handler);
    w.run();
}
```

Comment: `worker::run()` hardcodes `SomeResult` as the type of the result of the operation. So it must know a priori what type the handler expects, it seems. How would `AnotherResult` ever come into the picture?

Comment: I tried to describe it in the code comment, the actual work processing and determining of the result type is omitted. The type `SomeResult` is only hardcoded to have a simple and compilable example. In reality, the result type is dependant on the job type.

Comment: It is not clear where the actual problem lies. What exactly determines the result type? At which moment it becomes known? Your simplified example simplifies it too much.

Comment: If you are willing to use `boost::variant<SomeResult, AnotherResult>` to store the result, could you not also use `boost::variant<function<void(SomeResult)>, function<void(AnotherResult)> >` to store the handler?

Comment: Why don't you make abstract base of Result classes and down-cast it in handler functor?

Comment: This seems way overly-complicated.  In my experience, callbacks without a fixed signature are a recipe for unpleasantness.

Comment: I think the part that is missing is why do you need to have 2 parts in the job processing? (i.e. the actual work and the handler callback) The 2 parts seems completely coupled and should not even appear in your interface a separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is an overloaded (multi-signature) function, which you can find [here](https://github.com/jamboree/CxxFunctionBenchmark).
Since you're using Boost, for brevity I'll use Boost.TypeErasure here:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/builtin.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/callable.hpp>

template<class... Sig>
using overload =
    boost::type_erasure::any<
        boost::mpl::vector<
            boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
            boost::type_erasure::typeid_<>,
            boost::type_erasure::relaxed,
            boost::type_erasure::callable<Sig>...
        >
    >;
```

in your example, replace

```
std::function<void(const JobResultVariant&)>
```

with

```
overload<void(SomeResult const&), void(AnotherResult const&)>
```

Now you don't have to use variant, but it also means that the handler must handle all the type you listed, however, you can write a wrapper that fallbacks to do nothing:

```
struct whatever
{
    template<class T>
    whatever(T const&) {}
};

void do_nothing(whatever) {}

template<class F>
struct handler_wrapper : F
{
    using fallback = void(*)(whatever);

    handler_wrapper(F const& f) : F(f) {}

    operator fallback() const
    {
        return do_nothing;
    }
};
```

Inside `enqueue_job`, you can do

```
jobFinishedHandlerQueue.push(handler_wrapper<JobFinishedHandler>(handler));
```

In `run`, just call `finishedHandlerWrapper` with the either `SomeResult` or `AnotherResult`.